# htaccess prevent direct acces for all subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im developing an MVC pattern based CMS. 
I wnat to prevent the direct access to my subfolders and files
I have this .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
php_flag display_errors On
php_value error_reproting 9999

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
   RewriteEngine on
   SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
   RewriteBase /lmvc_trunk/

   Options -Indexes

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The page requests looks like: http://mydoamin.com/pages/details/15 . This will load the "pages" controller and call it's method called "details" and passes the 15 as a parameter (pages_controller->details(15))

The "Options -Indexes" will prevent users from listing for example the /library directory. But if I type http://mydoamin.com/library/Bootstrap.php in the browser it will load the php script.  I know if I add an .htaccess file with "deny from all" to a subfolder that will solve this problem, but isn't there any nicer solution than placing this htaccess file to ALL my subfolders? Can I somehow prevent the direct access to subfolders and files from the htaccess in the root?

It would be better if i could redirect direct file and folder requests to index/404 so the user wont even know if there is a folder called e.g /library

Im new to htacces and rewrite. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule as your **first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^/]+/\S+
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```